# displaying data with join tables using prepared statement

Tags: mysql

I have two different table and I will provide the image below. so the first table would be, tbl_students. The second table would be table_topicresearch and lastly tbl_requestforms. each unique ids of tbl_students and tbl_topic research are stored in tbl_requestforms for reducing the redundancy of the data. However I do not now on how to display the data in tbl_requestforms with prepared statement.

tbl_students
[image]

tbl_topicresearch
[image]

tbl_requestforms

[image]

SQL Code:

```
SELECT tbl_requestforms.ID, tbl_requestforms.request_id, tbl_topicresearch.research_title, tbl_topicresearch.researchTags, tbl_students.student_name 
FROM tbl_topicresearch, tbl_students, tbl_requestforms 
WHERE tbl_topicresearch.research_uid = tbl_students.student_id
```

I know that this query can display but I genuinely do not know the approach if using this kind of query applying a **procedural prepared statement**, I only used prepared statement when retrieving data from 1 table only.

Comment: A prepared statement isn't really necessary here since there are no variables or user input.

Comment: @aynber just want to clarify, so basically I only need to use prepared statement if the query has an input or variables that needs to be used? As long as there's no input/variables that the user will input just purely display only, there will be no need for prepared statement? Thank you.

Comment: Right. Prepared statements are for passing variables in securely, whether it's something you coded in, or user input. It's great so you don't need to worry about sanitizing input or making sure all of your quotes are matched correctly. But if there's nothing that needs to be quoted, no variables, and no user input, you don't need to prepare it.

Comment: It's best to use prepared statements every time. When you get into this habit you won't forget to use it when you need to include some data in the SQL

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with prepared statement though. You use them the same way every time. There's nothing special about joins. Show us what you tried already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to take a look at JOIN.

That Query could look like this:

`SELECT tbl_requestforms.ID, tbl_requestforms.request_id, tbl_topicresearch.research_title, tbl_topicresearch.researchTags, tbl_students.student_name FROM  tbl_requestforms JOIN  tbl_students ON  tbl_requestforms.student_id = tbl_students.student_id JOIN tbl_topicresearch ON tbl_requestforms.request_id=tbl_topicresearch.research_uid  WHERE WHERE tbl_topicresearch.research_uid = tbl_students.student_id;`

Using JOIN you can connect 2 or more tables based on a FK and a PK to get data more easily.

Think about `student_id` from students tables as a primary key and student_id from  tbl_requestforms is a foreign key and you can use that to connect 2 tables, from there you need to figure out what you need to connect with what.

P.S. Be careful because you can end up with pretty big query result if you make query like yours. It's row_count_table_1*row_count_table_2*row_count_table_3

Comment: Hello, is it possible to handle two primary key? as you can see in my tbl_students, my `ID` is already a `primary key` same goes with the tbl_topicresearch. If I make `ID` and `student_id` both primary key will there be an issue or not?

Comment: One should be a `primary key` for the for the table and one should be a `foreign key`

Comment: In your case ID it's the primary key for topicresearch and student_id it's the foreign key for the students table.
From what is see i don't think you need `id` and `research_id`, you can use the id from topicsearch to connect to the students table via a table of foreign keys that will contain an students.id and a topicreseach.id